# How to share Memory between applications ? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, memory

I will make 1 Application which constantly collects real time data in high speed

and 2nd application that processes the data and create new variables

and 3rd application uses the data

I want all the variables / data to be in physical memory as I'll have a server dedicated to this projects, and I don't want any use of the hard drive

How can this be achieved?

Many thanks

Comment: If it's all on the same server, why not just make one application with different threads/background processes?

Comment: You'll need to find another operating system.  Data in RAM is always backed by the hard disk.  If not from an explicit memory mapped file then by the paging file.  This is not a problem, modern machines have lots of RAM.

Comment: Basically I need to reserve a big block of physical memory for multiple applications to access

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to create a single application, which spawns 3 threads, and shares objects (be careful about deadlock/race conditions), or have 3 programs, which communicate via some medium (sockets, http etc) with serialization of the data as objects passed between them.

Comment: I just need a big block of physical memory to store a million integers and doubles , number of variables are fixed and will never change

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a DDE Server, is a old technology , where you can share data in memory into others applications. Actually is used in the programming of  PLC hardware to interchange data with other applications , like excel.

This technology can't be used on vb.Net , but you can still use vb6.
Example: in vb6 you can use the Label control property LinkTopic to share information .
And you can access to it from Excel cell while your appluication is still running.

I don't remember to much about it how to used but it easy and is still used on the manufacturing systems where they use the PLC hardware and this one place all information about the hardware status  in a memory called topic and others applications like excel can read this topics using the topic name (Is like the variable name)

Try to find more information in wikipeadia about DDE Servers and how to share information from vb6 topic property
[Topic property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235156%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: DDE is irrelevant to my requirements

Comment: Why you don't just open your imagination and create a Activex Dll in vb6
to read and populate the information of the memory and used on yourvb.net application like a bridge.

If the value change in the memory , the others applications will updated in realtime too.

I think this is the only way you can do it.
I saw in my last job how the DDE works greate but it was used by the mechatronics engineers to populate the information of the AllenBrandley PLC in realtime in memory and others application like system created in vb6 read this value with none problem of memory handle

Comment: I think there is  some components already developed for .net 
I found this video in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiPzqc5jDlE)